# Why does build fail with sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.2: not found?

Tags: sbt

We are suddenly getting failures on the build server (typesafe and maven repos are proxied through our internal  Nexus repo) for a project that successfully built with sbt 0.13.5  (tried upgrading to 0.13.6, still not working)  Any ideas?
EDIT: note, works fine when run locally

```
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/bisonadm/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-pgp/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.8.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-pgp/0.8.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-pgp_2.10_0.13/0.8.2/sbt-pgp-0.8.2.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-pgp:0.8.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-pgp:0.8.2 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
[warn]        +- org.scalastyle:scalastyle-sbt-plugin:0.5.0 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10) (/ahp_agents/ec/workspace/T_COMMON_master_full_CI_J4350527/common/project/plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]        +- default:common-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.2: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:243)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:158)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:64)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:119)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:116)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:147)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:156)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1282)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1279)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1309)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$84.apply(Defaults.scala:1307)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1312)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1306)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1324)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1264)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp;0.8.2: not found
```

Comment: workaround is manually add it to the ivy cache on the build server.  standard location: ~/.ivy2/cache/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-pgp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It appears they've moved to Bintray recently](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/commit/423c4dfab2ce23853e558f9dc70e998d6f7907e4) (and perhaps cleaning up other locations?).

With [the recent release of sbt-pgp 1.0-M1](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/releases/tag/v1.0-M1) I can find the plugin's binaries at https://bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/sbt-pgp/1.0-M1/view.

As you can read in Improvements in [0.13.6 Release Notes](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/tag/v0.13.6):

> Adds Resolver.jcenterRepo and Resolver.bintrayRepo(owner, repo) to add Bintray easier.

With all that said, the following worked for me (mind I haven't worked with the plugin before):

**project/sbt-pgp.sbt**

```
resolvers += Resolver.jcenterRepo

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.0-M1")
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

No other files were needed to boot sbt shell (with `sbt`) and query for available plugins:

```
> plugins
In file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/sbt-pgp/
    sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin: enabled in sbt-pgp
    sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin: enabled in sbt-pgp
    sbt.plugins.CorePlugin: enabled in sbt-pgp
    sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin: enabled in sbt-pgp
    com.typesafe.sbt.SbtPgp: enabled in sbt-pgp
```

Comment: That makes sense.  However, this being a corporate environment, we have to keep a copy of everything we need to build.  This requires us to use a proxy server (Nexus/Bower).  I have poked around a bit and I don't see any way to proxy jCenter.  Am I missing something or is the only way to have this stored locally is to manually upload it to my Nexus repo ?

Comment: Since the answer of mine was accepted, how did you work it around/sorted it out?

Comment: The move to Bintray was the root of the issue.  I am manually maintaining the ivy cache on the build server until I can either get the dependency management hooked up to Bower and use our internal Bower repo or just bail on sbt and find an alternative (gradle?)  I've pretty much had it with sbt at this point, I've been battling this kind of stuff for months now.

Comment: I've never tried it out before, but an idea came to my mind to keep the plugin within the project is to save the plugin's binaries under `project/lib` directory. It could work.

Comment: That would work, however it's generally best to keep binaries out of your source.

Comment: Oh, and I found a repo with sbt-pgp version that I was looking for:   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/